# merge 2 tables without common column

Tags: sql, join

I have a scenario where i need to merge 2 tables. but there are no common columns between the two tables.

Table 1

```
    ---------------
    |grpnr|grpname|
    ---------------
    | 1   |abc    |              
    | 2   |def    |             
    | 3   |ghi    |              
    ---------------
```

Table 2

```
    ----------------
    | no | text    |   
    ----------------  
    | 0  | qwerty  | 
    | 10 | asdfg   |
    | 25 | zxcvb   | 
    ----------------
```

Expected result

```
  -------------------------------
  | grpnr | Grpname| no| text   |
  -------------------------------
  |  1    | abc    | 0 | qwerty |
  |  1    | abc    |10 | asdfg  |
  |  1    | abc    |25 | zxcvb  |
  |  2    | def    | 0 | qwerty | 
  |  2    | def    |10 | asdfg  |
  |  2    | def    |25 | zxcvb  | 
  |  3    | ghi    | 0 | qwerty | 
  |  3    | ghi    |10 | asdfg  | 
  |  3    | ghi    |25 | zxcvb  | 
  -------------------------------
```

I tried using sql joins but im not able to achieve the desired result. can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Have you tried `cross join`? `SELECT * FROM table1 CROSS JOIN table2;`

Comment: @voidpro Thanks alot!! It was so simple and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried cross join?

```
SELECT Table1.col1,  
       Table1.col2,
       Table2.col1,  
       Table2.col2
FROM tablename Table1
CROSS JOIN tablename Table2;
```

additional info for this http://www.w3resource.com/sql/joins/cross-join.php

Comment: Numbers are not preferred for aliasing a table or column. You may modify the answer accordingly.

Comment: @voidpro even though it is not the point of the question itself ill still follow your recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT
  *
FROM Table_2 t1
CROSS JOIN Table_4 t2
ORDER BY t1.grpnr;
```

[image: output]